# asp.net mvc jquery ui datepicker binding issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I am developing asp.net mvc3 project on windows 7, vs 2010. I have added jquery and jquery ui references to project.

I have a form that saves data to database. In my form I have a textbox which binded editor template for show date picker.

If I publish the project on my computer (windows 7 IIS 7) everything works correctly.
But When I upload the published project to server (Windows 2003 IIS 6) the date picker value is not correct error occuring.

**Editor Template**

```
@model Nullable<System.DateTime>

@Html.TextBox(  "", 
                Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") :string.Empty, 
                new { data_datepicker = true, @class = "text-box " })
```

**Javascript code for format datepicker**

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['tr']);
$.datepicker.setDefaults({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
    minDate: 0
});

$(":input[data-datepicker]").datepicker();
```

})

**My POST action is**

```
public ActionResult Create(FormViewModel formModel)
{

}
```

FormViewModel contains name and date properties. I thiks  Model binder is not bind date. because name property field is true, date property is gets error.

**Error:**
The value '18.07.2012' is not valid for EndDate.]

Comment: Can you post the error that you are getting?  Also are you sure that the server has jQuery installed (if the scripts are local)?

Comment: Erro Message is [The value '18.07.2012' is not valid for EndDate.] Jquery are uploaded successful.

Comment: Could be a date format issue if the locale of your computer and the server are different.

Comment: My local is turkish regional settings, server was united states settings. But I setted the server turkish regional settings. (I updated post now)

Answer (score 1):

I solved problem. The culture difference issue is my problem. I set the web configuration file.
`<globalization culture="tr-TR" />`

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it works locally. I would think you need something like:

```
$('.text-box').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation in which my solution was working perfectly locally, but when deployed on Windows Server 2012 , the date field was setting to 01/01/0000 :00 00 00 upon form submission.

I added the globilization tag in my Web.Config such as

```
<globalization culture="en-US" />
```

and it works fine now.